# How to send multi chunk data using nghttp2?

Tags: http2, nghttp2, avs

I am using the nghttp2 library to format the multipart frames to communicate with Alexa. I am currently able to get the response of audio with a multipart message. But, currently it is only possible to send data up to 16KB, I want to do streaming of my recorded data which can be greater than 16KB as a whole.

Can anyone please help me in sending the audio data in the chunk to the AVS using nghttp2?

Looking forward to the response, please help.

Thanks.

In addition, I am adding the reference functions from the code. Please ignore the name convention and other logic as I am just trying this ruffly to send the data over 16KB size.

```
    //Callback function for the data to be send to the server
ssize_t data_prd_read_callback_1(nghttp2_session *session, int32_t stream_id, uint8_t *buf, size_t length,uint32_t *data_flags, nghttp2_data_source *source, void *user_data)
{
    //uint8_t send_data[8000]; 
    char send_data[] = "\r\n\r\n--_____FINISH_HERE__________\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"metadata\"\r\nContent-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n{\"context\":[{\"header\": {\"namespace\": \"SpeechSynthesizer\",\"name\": \"SpeechState\"},\"payload\": {\"token\":\"\",\"offsetInMilliseconds\":0,\"playerActivity\":\"IDLE\"}}],\"event\":{\"header\":{\"namespace\":\"SpeechRecognizer\",\"name\":\"Recognize\",\"messageId\":\"MID-123456\",\"dialogRequestId\":\"DRID-123456\"},\"payload\":{\"profile\":\"CLOSE_TALK\",\"format\":\"AUDIO_L16_RATE_16000_CHANNELS_1\"}}}\r\n\r\n--_____FINISH_HERE__________\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"audio\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";

    int fd = source->fd;
    uint8_t *audio_data;
    uint8_t *final_data_end, *temp_data;
    audio_data = malloc(AUDIO_FILE_SIZE);
    memset(audio_data, 0, AUDIO_FILE_SIZE);
    final_data_end = malloc(MAX_SIZE_TO_SEND);
    temp_data = final_data_end;
    memset(final_data_end, 0, MAX_SIZE_TO_SEND);
    int r;
    r = read(fd, audio_data, AUDIO_FILE_SIZE);
    if ( r == -1)
    {
        printf("JOSHI error while reading audio file\n");
    }
    int len, i;
    len = strlen(send_data);
    memcpy(final_data_end, send_data, strlen(send_data));
    final_data_end += strlen(send_data);
    memcpy(final_data_end, audio_data, AUDIO_FILE_SIZE);
    final_data_end += AUDIO_FILE_SIZE;
    memcpy(final_data_end, "\r\n--_____FINISH_HERE__________--", 32);
    memcpy(buf, temp_data, (strlen(send_data) + AUDIO_FILE_SIZE + 32));
    return (strlen(send_data) + AUDIO_FILE_SIZE + 32);
}


static int send_request(struct connection *conn, struct request *req) {
    nghttp2_nv nva[] = { 
                MAKE_NV_LL(":method", "POST"),
                MAKE_NV_L(":scheme", "https"),
                MAKE_NV_LL(":path", "/v20160207/events" ),
        MAKE_NV_LL("authorization", "Bearer "ACCESS_TOKEN""),
        MAKE_NV_LL("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=_____FINISH_HERE__________")};
    int rv;

    nghttp2_data_provider data_prd;
    int file_descriptor;
    file_descriptor = open ("./audio.raw", O_RDONLY);
    if (file_descriptor == -1)
    {
        printf("error while reading the audio file\n");
    }
    data_prd.source.fd = file_descriptor;   // set the file descriptor 
    data_prd.read_callback = data_prd_read_callback_1;

    rv = nghttp2_submit_request(conn->ngh2, NULL, nva, ARRLEN(nva), &data_prd, req);
    temp_stream_id = rv;
    if (rv < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "In second error: (nghttp2_submit_requset) %s\n",nghttp2_strerror(rv));
        return -1; 
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

I am using "nghttp2_session_send" for the sending with send_callback function. 
Whenever I try with file beyond the 16KB size AVS will reply with ERROR "there is no multipart data with status:400". If the whole data is less than 16KB then alexa will reply with audio data attached in response.

Comment: Show your code. What did you try?

Comment: Yes, I have attached the code in question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specity to nghttp that you did not finish writing.
As written in [tutorial](https://nghttp2.org/documentation/tutorial-server.html):

```
static ssize_t file_read_callback(nghttp2_session *session _U_,
                                  int32_t stream_id _U_, uint8_t *buf,
                                  size_t length, uint32_t *data_flags,
                                  nghttp2_data_source *source,
                                  void *user_data _U_) {
  int fd = source->fd;
  ssize_t r;
  while ((r = read(fd, buf, length)) == -1 && errno == EINTR)
    ;
  if (r == -1) {
    return NGHTTP2_ERR_TEMPORAL_CALLBACK_FAILURE;
  }
  if (r == 0) {
    *data_flags |= NGHTTP2_DATA_FLAG_EOF;
  }
  return r;
}
```

You can see that they set the *data_flags to NGHTTP2_DATA_FLAG_EOF when there is no more data to read.
So if you have several MB file and only 16k buffer then you have to keep some offset and in every call of your data_prd_read_callback_1 write max 16k and then in the last iteration write the rest (say 10k or whatever is left).
I use it this way:

```
ssize_t Message::Http2DataLoader( nghttp2_session *sess, int32_t sId, uint8_t *buf, size_t bufLen, uint32_t *dataFlags, nghttp2_data_source *src, void *hint )
{
   ssize_t ret = 0;
   Message* theRes = reinterpret_cast< Message* >( src->ptr );

   if ( bufLen <= theRes->getDataLen() - theRes->getWritten() )
   {
      std::memcpy( buf, theRes->getData() + theRes->getWritten(), bufLen );
      ret = bufLen;
   }
   else
   {
      std::memcpy( buf, theRes->getData() + theRes->getWritten(), theRes->getDataLen() - theRes->getWritten() );
      ret = theRes->getDataLen() - theRes->getWritten();
   }

   theRes->addWritten( ret );

   if( theRes->AllDataConsumed() )
   {
      *dataFlags |= NGHTTP2_DATA_FLAG_EOF;
   }

   return ret;
}
```

The Message class is a container that can contain either body data or multiparts, all multiparts when added writes its data to internal Message buffer and then in the dataloader callback I just write it in 16k chunks (or better say in **bufLen** chunks). I keep track where am I in the buffer using **addWritten** and **getWritten** methods. The competition is handled by **AllDataConsumed**.
If you are reading the audio multipart from file then you need something like the file_read_callback from tutorial. It would be good if you encapsulate that into some *Message* class where you can add some json multipart and audio multipart and modify the dataLoader callback to first write the json part and then start reading the audio file and adding writing it to **buf** in **16k(*bufLen*)** chunks.

The ***nghttp2_session_send*** will call your *data_prd_read_callback_1* until you write all your data or some error happens. This means that you can handle the JSON write to buffer and audio file write to buffer as you need. If everything goes well it will be just calling your callback until you set the ***data_flags to NGHTTP2_DATA_FLAG_EOF**.

Hope this helps you.